# Deserialization when sometimes its object, sometimes field

Tags: java

I'm facing a problem with derserialization json, because if in response there is a field insted of object it's not working and I'm not sure how can I figure it it out. Below it's my code

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Person {

    @JsonProperty
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty
    private String email;

    @JsonProperty
    private Company company;
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Company {

    @JsonProperty
    private String name;

}
```

when json look like this:

```
  {
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
```

everything its working fine, and I'm using this to map to List

```
objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<>() {});
```

but when json is:

```
{
"name":"Flss",
"email":"ffirebrace9@independent.co.uk",
"companyName":"Realpoint"
}
```

its not working. I've tried use @JsonAlias and @JsonCreatot but still no luck. Can anyone have any idea how can I resolve this?

Comment: Your object doesn't have a field named companyName

Comment: @KęstutisRamulionis I dont want to create another field name, I want to set Company name.

Comment: Then it should look like this: ```"name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona"}```

Comment: @KęstutisRamulionis yeah, but what if I have two different endpoints with two different json response and I want to have only one Person class.

Comment: This is really just fundamentals of OOP. In short, if you have two endpoints, the one returning a ```human```, the other one a ```dog```, even though they both have field ```name```, you are not gonna store them into ```human``` or a ```dog``` object, right? In that case you will have to create two separate objects for each different response and deserialize depending on the endpoint and expected response.

Comment: You can either make another class ```CompanyPerson```, which will contain ```companyName``` for example or just add additional optional field to ```Person``` class named ```companyName```

Comment: @KęstutisRamulionis I've added `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` to `Person class`, then added one field `companyName` and by jstl expression `{Person.company.name || person.companyName}` and its working fine